# postgresql foreign key integer[] refers to integer

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key-relationship

i'm working on a postgresql database and i have an issue :

i want to create a table applicant with a column categories_ids (that mean that an applicant can have multiple categories) and i want create a foreign key constraint between this column and the column id of categories table. But pgadmin says that is impossible :

```
foreign key constraint "fk_categories_ids" cannot be implemented
DÉTAIL : Key columns "categories_ids" and "id" are of incompatible types: integer[] and integer.
```

EDIT 1 :

```
CREATE TABLE public.applicants
(
-- Hérité(e) from table users:  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass),
-- Hérité(e) from table users:  email character(60) NOT NULL,
-- Hérité(e) from table users:  "firstName" character(50) NOT NULL,
-- Hérité(e) from table users:  "lastName" character(50) NOT NULL,
-- Hérité(e) from table users:  password character(50) NOT NULL,
-- Hérité(e) from table users:  role_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_role_id_seq'::regclass),
  home boolean NOT NULL,
  "fullTime" boolean,
  "partTime" boolean NOT NULL,
  freelance boolean NOT NULL,
  internship boolean NOT NULL,
  "minSalary" integer,
  domain_id integer,
  categories_ids integer[],
  skills_ids integer[],
  locations_ids integer[],
  "jobExperiences_ids" integer[],
  CONSTRAINT pk_applicant_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_domain_id FOREIGN KEY (domain_id)
      REFERENCES public.domains (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
INHERITS (public.users)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Comment: This is simply not supported. Normalize your data model, then you can create a proper foreign key

Comment: yes but i don't know how to model this comportment i am really just starting working on databases could you show me how i could do ?

Comment: You are looking for a "one-to-many relationship" in relational design

Comment: yes absolutely an applicant can have many categories

Comment: There was a patch for this, IIRC, but it didn't make it in due to performance concerns and wasn't re-submitted. So it's not supported. For more info search for "foreign key array patch"

Comment: @CraigRinger this exactly what i'm looking for but there is no option in the constraint menu to do this so maybe you know how to write the SQL code directly ine the SQL pannel which is read only ?

Comment: Show the tables definitions. `\d my_table` in psql.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `categories_ids integer[]` field and:

```
create table applicant_category (
    applicant_id int references applicants(id),
    category_id int references category(category_id),
    primary key (applicant_id, category_id)
)
```

Comment: This is traditional approach, EAV. It can be worse or can be better, depending on concrete circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create FK on array column. Not supported.
So either use EAV model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model, so 3 tables instead of 2), or work without Foreign Keys (you can create custom triggers to emulate them, though).

There are some articles comparing EAV with using "non-primitive" (`int[]`, `hstore`, `jsonb`) data types -- for example http://coussej.github.io/2016/01/14/Replacing-EAV-with-JSONB-in-PostgreSQL/ and [https://wiki.hsr.ch/Datenbanken/files/Benchmark_of_KVP_vs.*hstore*-_doc.pdf](https://wiki.hsr.ch/Datenbanken/files/Benchmark_of_KVP_vs._hstore_-_doc.pdf) have some benchmarks.